# Onclick On Radio Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this radio button and text field in a form. When the page loads, the disable field method gets called and disables the text field. What I am trying to do next is to re enable the text field by activating the radio button. Hence I have an onclick event on the radio button that calls the enablefield method. But its refusing to reactivate the textfield. Is it the syntax you reckon?

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="asiinternship" value="Tadween Publishing" onclick="enableField(applyingforother)" />Other <input type="text" name="applyingforother" maxlength="56" style="width:143px;margin-bottom:20px;" />
</form>

<script>
        function enableField(myField)
            {
            myField.disabled = false
            return true
            }   

        function disableField(myField)
            {
            myField.disabled = true
            return true
            }       

        disableField(document.forms["contact_form"].applyingforother)

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes:

```
 onclick="enableField(applyingforother)
```

should be:

```
 onclick="enableField('applyingforother')
```

Comment: Accordingo to ECMA script 5.x you need also a ; at the end.

Comment: Tried that, didnt seem to do the trick :/

Claudio a semi colon where? at the end of 'applyingforother'?